# How to restore an untracked file listed in .git/info/exclude?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

First I wanted to ignore the `config/environments/development.rb`, so i added it into `.git/info/exclude`, and it worked. When I wanted to make it visible among my untacked files I deleted that line from `.git/info/exclude`.

However, when I change the file `config/environments/development.rb`, `git status` doesn't list it as an untracked file. Why is that?

Comment: I have found it, just execute `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged File`

Comment: Although Google is pretty good about spelling errors, you will find more on this if you spell "untracked" correctly: there is an R after the T. If `--no-assume-unchanged` helped, though, you *did not have an untracked file* in the first place. A tracked file is one that is in the index; hence, an *un*-tracked file is one that is *not* in the index. The "assume unchanged" flag can only be set or cleared on an index entry, which means the file must be in the index, which means the file must necessarily already be tracked.